# Android Studio Date Picker Missing Selection Problem

Tags: java, android, android-studio, datepicker, android-datepicker

I have problem that the selection to be omitted when i click on the last week days.
I tried to adjust the values such as padding, margin, and area size as much as possible, but there was no result.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
<DatePicker
            style="@style/DatePickerTheme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="410dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:datePickerMode="spinner"
            android:scaleX="1.1"
            android:scaleY="1.1"
            android:spinnersShown="false"
            android:theme="@style/DatePickerTheme" />

<style name="DatePickerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#734C23</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">410.8dp</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">400dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">0dp</item>
    
</style>
```

Comment: Why it the `scaleX` and `scaleY` needed?

Comment: As I tried to fit the size I wanted, I ended up using scaleX and scaleY.
There was a limit to adjusting the size from themes.xml with minWidth and minHeight.

Comment: Can you add an image to show what problem you are exactly facing?

Comment: I really want to add an image, but I just joined stackoverflow, so adding images is limited...

Comment: Use imgur and add it as a link to your code

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/8Eg77Uv

Comment: I haven't set up a pop-up yet, so just look at the date picker!
The date picker area is from the separation line at the top to the buttons at the bottom.
I gave the padding value to zero because I thought it was a margin problem, but there is still an unknown margin.